# Not expected out in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to run the below code but in the second console command the returning value is 'undefined'.
Help me with this

```
enum MobilePrice {Black= 25000, Gold= 28000, White= 30000}

// functon to calculate final amount
function calculateAmount(price: number): number {
    let discount: number;
    let totalAmount: number;
    if (price === MobilePrice.Gold) {
      discount = 5;
    } else if (price === MobilePrice.White) {
      discount = 8;
    } else {
    discount = 10;
           }
    totalAmount = price - price * discount / 100;
    return totalAmount;
}

// lines to populate the Actual and Final price of Black color Mobile
console.log('Actual price of the Mobile is ' + MobilePrice.Black);
console.log('The final price after discount is ' + calculateAmount(MobilePrice.Black));
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAsg9gIwJYBtgAUBOSDGwoDeAQigIY4DWAvFAEwCsADMwDRQDicKAJjbQBzNGbAOoALJABdgNAMxDGAXwCwAKABmYEDklI4IKDlIocYMtICCEOFskAKAA7Y8ALijgICYJgCUbj16YhGpQoVBoklDcSADOODYgkv6QgQDcIWERUJJwksZWCUnuKd7pqmFQSOpQjs74VA2wiKgYdQB0nDw+weUVUbHxtlA09GUVilDAKDH4VTVOuPWN8MhoWItt4lLA3QQZFdFxhcNQ-GNhE1MzPQcDxzQAjIznfeP72bn51kM0C3hQAFooH98AAqfpHIYAeigT2e70wwEkYEwBhyeRQBVsZRUqniIBiXGAbRQcAA5nYAOQWHRgYzAupQODVSRifArFqVGJQSlQADUTVWrQ2JHIFB8ZXxhLQJPJVIAKmyoOokCB6SCoKR1NIgodBokuTz+YZjKZzMAsYk7By1u1RZQfBKgA): `The final price after discount is 22500`

Comment: Please try to produce a [mcve] as described in [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz calculateAmount(MobilePrice.Black) is displaying undefined

Comment: Just tried and it works.

Comment: @Mutharasan It displays `22500` for me and for everyone else who has replied so far.  If you are seeing something different you need to debug your environment, or post enough information for someone else to reproduce it.  It is unlikely that anyone else can do that for you.  Are you *sure* you are running the same code you've posted?